# What does "i for i" do and how does it work? Is it useful for anything beyond indexing in lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

When I was searching how to find the index of items in a list, the answer included some code that I  couldn't figure out.

Specifically this:

```
[i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']
```

I understood most of it but the '`i for i`' segment has left me confused.
I am very familiar with normal `for` loops but I do not understand this, can someone please explain?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

I like to break [list comprehensions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) up into normal for loops to help me understand what they're doing (or in troubleshooting one of my own).

```py
output = [i for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']) if j == 'bar']
```

is the same as:

```py
output = []
for i, j in enumerate(['foo', 'bar', 'baz']):
    if j == 'bar':
        output.append(i)
```

List comprehensions, especially large ones, run faster than a traditional for loop.